# How to fix a variable on a page

Tags: php

I am getting a variable from another page but when I click on faculty link the get variable destroy. How I fix the variable on this page?

```
<ul>
<?php if(isset($_GET['a'])){$var=$_GET['a'];};?>
<li><a href='<?php if(isset($var)){echo $var;} ?>.php'><span><?php if(isset($var))
{echo             $var." ";}?>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href=''><span>HOD</span></a></li>
<li><a href='faculty.php?b=<?php if(isset($_GET['a'])){echo $_GET['a'];}?>'>
<span>Faculty</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are using `?b=` as parameter, but `$_GET["a"]` in the code. Probably that?

Comment: use `$_GET['b']` in faculty.php to access the value.

Comment: are you sure about your `$_GET["a"]` variable has any value??

Comment: @webomnizz yes it's getting.I can see when page load but it is not storing on the page when I click another link it destroy. and using b variable I am again sending the get variable to another page it's working no an issue.

Comment: @DheerajSharma `"when I click another link it destroy"`, `$_GET['a']` variable works when it exists in the URL like "index.php?a=somevalue" and if you click again on some link like "clickagain.php?b=somevalue" then only `$_GET['b']` works not `$_GET['a']`.

Comment: @DheerajSharma if you want to access the `a` variable in some another link you should pass this variable in next clicked url, like "anotherurl.php?a=somevalue&b=someanothervalue"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect just make sure your `URL` must have `a` as  `index.php?a=somevalue`.

```
<ul>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['a']))
        {
            $var=$_GET['a'];
    ?>
        <li>
            <a href = ""<?php echo $var; ?>.php" rel="">
                <span><?php echo $var." "; ?>Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href = ''><span>HOD</span></a></li>
        <li>
            <a href = "faculty.php?b=<?php echo $var; ?>" rel="">
                <span>Faculty</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanx Dipesh Parmar.I did it but forgot about url variable a when moving to another page. still I am not satisfied with my code its very complex I am working to reduce it...Prob is when I will add more link the. Will I have to repeat this code again?

Comment: you already checking $_GET['a'] after ul tag so just use $var in faculty link...initially set it as $var= "";

Comment: @DheerajSharma see my updated answer code block..

Comment: @DheerajSharma always welcome brother... you should accept answer.